# How big a black hole is needed for this story?

Tags: internal-consistency, hard-science, astronomy, black-holes, natural-disasters

The story begins in classic disaster film style.  A small rogue black hole is approaching our Solar System. It isn’t going to get close enough to destroy everything, but it will agitate our Sun, causing horrific solar flares as it reaches perihelion. Those flares are going to bake the Earth’s surface in fatal levels of radiation.  Conservative estimates suggest that it will take a thousand years for the planet’s magnetic fields to recover, at which time it will be fit for recolonization.

We don’t have FTL travel and we’ve only got a decade to prepare, so the world unites in an effort to build a fleet of generation ships capable of holding ten thousand souls, plus a Noah’s ark assortment of domesticated animals. The trick will be to keep that viable gene pool alive for a thousand years in deep space.  The finest minds alive work on the problem, but there is just no way to bring even a fraction of the oxygen, food and water needed.

In desperation, an insane plan is adopted.

The ships will launch about a year before perihelion and will proceed on a collision course with the approaching black hole. At the moment when the singularity passes closest to our Sun, the ships will dive into its gravity well, slingshoting in close enough to the event horizon to cause significant time dilation.

Emerging after half an orbit of the hole (by firing Orion nuclear engines to reach escape velocity), they will race back towards earth, arriving just before the life support supplies run out. If the time dilation does what it should, the fleet's two year round trip, will find an Earth more than a thousand years older and completely healed.

Now for my question…

**What combination of black hole size/mass and distance from our Solar System would make this story viable?**

- It needs to get close enough that an Orion nuclear drive (and maybe a
  sun-dive/slingshot outbound maneuver) can get our ships there in a
  relatively short time (so that we don’t run out of life support on
  the way there).
- It needs to be small enough that it doesn’t rip Earth out of its
  orbit as it passes by.  It can take the rest of the planets, but
  Earth and our moon have to survive.
- It needs to be big enough that it can generate enough time dilation
  that a thousand years can pass on Earth during the fleet’s one or two
  year journey.

One additional question…

**Is it believable that a cosmically short-term interaction with a distant black hole, could temporarily cause our sun to intensify, throwing off solar flare for a few years before settling back down to normal?**

Comment: With a powerful and reliable energy source, the ship doesn't need to carry 1000 years of food, water, oxygen, it can recycle everything. With enough energy, if the ship can maintain 1G of acceleration for 30 years, time dilation means 30 years of ship time is 1000 years of earth time. I think that any black hole long enough to allow survivable surfing of the event horizon would be so massive that it would absorb the entire solar system, including the Sun. Though the best chance of survival is probably in deep caves on earth until the fatal radiation passes rather than a hastily built ship.

Comment: Getting that close to a black hole will likely cause significant http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_force, to the point where your ship will be ripped apart.

Comment: If the black hole passes too near to the earth , wont it cause time dilation on earth as well? Can somebody please educate me on this?

Comment: There is another big problem here as well - time dilation means the ship will only experience 30 years...however the black hole will still have flown through space for 1000 years. When you complete the sling shot you will be a LONG way from earth.

Comment: @DanSmolinske  Unless it's big enough.  But it would have to be truly massive to not be lethal.

Comment: _"It needs to be small enough that it doesn’t rip Earth out of its orbit as it passes by. It can take the rest of the planets, but Earth and our moon have to survive."_ Well, Earth and our moon _wouldn't_ survive if the rest of the planets got ripped away. The whole solar system is in balance!

Comment: @Lightning..., Intuitively, I didn't agree with you about the effect of loosing planets, so I jumped over to the physics stackexchange to check.  I found a [question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/64549/how-reliant-is-the-solar-system-on-being-exactly-the-way-it-is) on exactly that subject and It turns out you are right (+1), at least in terms of Jupiter and Saturn.  I will edit my question later tonight.  Thanks!

Comment: One important note: perigee is the closest pass to Earth; the closest pass to the Sun is called the perihelion.

Comment: @Henry: np :)​​

Comment: And while the loons are playing with spacecraft I'm going to simply dig in and build an underground city.  Any level of radiation that will leave the world intact when it's over isn't going to matter even 50' down.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

That's some extreme time dilation.

It is possible, but the black hole needs to be insanely massive for your ship to orbit it without falling into the event horizon and have the proper amount of time pass.

[Gravitational time dilation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_time_dilation) goes like this:

$$t_0 = t_f \sqrt{1-{{r_0}\over{r}}}$$

Where,

- $t_0$ is the proper time between events A and B for a slow-ticking
  observer within the gravitational field
- $t_f$ is the coordinate time between events A and B for a
  fast-ticking observer at an arbitrarily large distance from the
  massive object
- $r$ is the radial coordinate of the observer (which is analogous to
  the classical distance from the center of the object, but is actually
  a Schwarzschild coordinate)
- $r_0 = {{2GM}\over{c^2}}$ is the Schwarzschild radius of M.

I initially solved this by estimating the *insane* minimum distance of 1km from the event horizon. This was supposed to be a minimum bound for the size of the black hole, but it appears to not be insane enough. You said you wanted half an orbit, a slingshot, it's hard to say how long that would take. I'm guessing a tenth of one year; about five weeks.

$$0.1\ year = 1000\ years \sqrt{1-{{r_0}\over{r_0 + 1000\ meters}}}$$

Solving this gives a Schwarzschild radius of about 99,999,999,000 meters. Which requires 33,851,584 solar masses to produce. This would be a supermassive black hole larger than the one at the center of our galaxy. Larger by almost an order of magnitude.

To have such a thing pass near enough to our solar system that the ship could get there in one year is likely to do more than make our sun fizzle a bit. Placing the black hole farther away means it needs to be even more massive in order to make up for the extra travel time. Which might not work anyway because the ship would also have to orbit in less time, which starts to become impossible as the black hole gets larger.

To make this story plausible, the elapsed time needs to be significantly reduced. Unfortunately that reduction would likely need to be to less than ten years. Even getting closer to the black hole doesn't solve it. Getting to just ten meters away still requires a black hole of around 338,500 solar masses. But, 1km was already insane and very likely impossible to achieve.

I don't think a passing black hole is a viable method for "intensifying" our Sun's weather. I can't think of anything you could do to the Sun to make it act weirdly for only 1000 years, it's been around for so much longer than that.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  It appears to be one of those cases where a good story premise and science have no common ground, so the story will die unwritten.  +1 for all your efforts with the math.  Thanks again!

Comment: Great answer ... and you neglected to mention the complicating effects of tidal stresses such close approaches would impose.  While 100 km from the event horizon might be safe for a 33,000,000 solar mass black hole, I sincerely doubt 10 km from the event horizon for a 330,000 solar mass black hole is.

Comment: @HenryTaylor Don't let it die, this is a brilliant story, and I want to read it. I do believe that a sufficient amount of Unobtanium in the hull will allow a ship to pass very close to the event horizon with only minimal adverse effect! Let's not let boring fact get in the way of a good story!

Comment: Would it be possible to orbit the black hole at a survivable distance for say, ten years? I wonder if that would help the math work out. As far as the black hole travelling away for 1000 years, perhaps this black hole isn't just passing through the system, perhaps it showed up some time ago and isn't going to be leaving anytime soon. Maybe it's on a near parallel path to the sun, so it doesn't get too far away in 1000 years. Now, you can leave Earth, spend a few years getting to the black hole. Spend 10 years in orbit. Then, spend a couple decades on the return trip.

Comment: You get back within a generation and 1000 years have passed on Earth. As far as the black hole causing the sun to fry the Earth being unlikely, maybe just have some other catastrophe that will make the Earth uninhabitable for 1000 years, perhaps even our own doing or otherwise unrelated to the black hole. Then, the black hole showing up could actually be the savior of mankind.

Comment: @Jim2B That's exactly why flying so close is likely impossible. Tidal stress was already mentioned in the comments.

Comment: @Samuel, sorry I didn't see that.  I also agree that a story like this would be very neat.  Are the originally stated numbers "set in stone" or can we play with them to make it more realistic?

Comment: @Bryon Yes, orbiting for a longer time significantly reduces the requisite size of the black hole. It's directly related, one year would be ten times smaller than a tenth of a year, ten years would be ten times smaller than that, etc.

Comment: @Jim2B The specifications I gathered were: two years on board the ship, half an orbit, and one thousand years passed on Earth. All the others seem variable within reason.

Comment: @HenryTaylor in summary, certain story elements (time dialation) push you to use a supermassive BH.  Other story elements (maintaining the structure of the solar system while causing the sun to flare) require low (perhaps sub-stellar) mass BH.  The former leads to other questions such as "how come we didn't spot it early" and "what effects does it have on the rest of the galaxy?"  The latter leads to questions about "how would you form a sub-stellar mass black hole?"

Comment: Please don't let this die. It sounds incredible.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments.  I will renew my efforts to make this story work.    All of your efforts and support are greatly appreciated.  After work today, I'm going to modify the question, dropping flight-time limitations and maybe working in Byron's parallel course idea.  Maybe then we can create a scientifically feasible version of this story.  Thanks Again To All!

Answer (score 6):

This is probably more of a comment than an answer, but as I don't have enough reputation to comment I'll see how this goes:

Have you considered using a [cosmic string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_string) instead of a black hole?  You might be able to still get the time dilation effect due to the string acting like it has high mass, and the crew could travel along the length of the string as it passes near the solar system so they exit at the other end of the string, still near the solar system but at a time when the string has passed out of harm's way (rather than with the black hole where they would exit very far from where they started).

Comment: Good idea!  I've been reworking the question over the weekend, and no matter how I play with the numbers, I can't seem to get the non-ftl ships far enough away from the solar system to make the wandering black hole harmless.  I will look into your cosmis strings as an alternative.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose I'll address the solar flares angle, since nobody appears to have tried that yet.

My main objection here is that an external source will have a very hard time causing solar flares. Solar flares are, at their hearts, magnetic phenomena. While the exact mechanism behind them is unknown, one fundamental component is [charged particles traveling along magnetic field lines](http://solar-center.stanford.edu/FAQ/Qsolflares.html), formed inside the star. There are various ideas as to the events that lead to these particles being ejected:  kink instabilities in coronal loops ([Wood & Priest (1979)](http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-iarticle_query?1979SoPh...64..303H&data_type=PDF_HIGH&whole_paper=YES&type=PRINTER&filetype=.pdf)), coronal mass ejections (discussed in [Zhang et al. (2001)](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1086/322405/pdf;jsessionid=EF05A679DC3EBC3828CAB19FFEF5278B.c1.iopscience.cld.iop.org)), or more exotic structures ([Kusano et al. (2012)](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0004-637X/760/1/31/pdf)). A good overview of many different theories is given in [Shibata (2011)](http://solarphysics.livingreviews.org/Articles/lrsp-2011-6/download/lrsp-2011-6Color.pdf).

The point is, an external source is most likely not going to cause solar flares. It's true that black holes can have magnetic fields, but, [as I explained here](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/13570/how-does-an-accreting-black-hole-acquire-magnetic-fields/13580#13580), they are generated by the accretion disk surrounding the black hole, not the black hole itself. You would need to have it bring its accretion disk along with it for it to have a magnetic field itself, which would really screw up the Solar System in other ways - and still probably not cause solar flares, unless you take into account the other extreme consequences of a black hole entering the Solar System.